# JNDI local lookup for enterprise beans within the same module

Tags: jndi, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

Here are some lines from the Java EE 6 tutorial about JNDI local lookup.

*The java:app namespace is used to look up local enterprise beans packaged within the same application. That is, the enterprise bean is packaged within an EAR file containing multiple Java EE modules. JNDI addresses using the java:app namespace are of the following form:*

***java:app[/module name]/enterprise bean name[/interface name]***

*The module name is optional. The interface name is required only if the enterprise bean implements more than one business interface.*

**My question is:** Why is the module name optional? What if there are two enterprise beans with the same name in two different modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module name is not optional if you deploy an EAR.  The module name is omitted if you deploy a WAR or EJB JAR directly without packaging it within an EAR because in that case, there is only one module so there is no ambiguity.

Comment: By module, are we referring to a conventional Java package that contains classes?

Comment: No, "module" in this context is a Java EE term that means either a WAR file, an EJB JAR file, an application client JAR file, or a RAR file.  An EAR file consists of a set of module files and other library JAR files.

Comment: Hi Brett Kail, I have one last concern about this. What if my EJB JAR file has two packges in it: com.test.pkg1 and com.test.pkg2 and each containing MyEJB.java? So, wouldn't there be a collision between com.test.pkg1.MyEJB and com.test.pkg2.MyEJB during JNDI lookup?

Comment: Enterprise bean names must be distinct within an EJB JAR, so the EJB JAR would fail deployment in your example unless you explicitly rename one of them (e.g., `@Stateless(name="MyEJB2")`).

Comment: (Note, that restriction exists regardless of whether the EJB JAR is packaged within an EAR file or not, so it's mostly tangential to the optionality of the module name.)